# A remote for a fluorescent lamp pull chain

Tags: lighting

I have a fluorescent lamp deep in my closet with a pull chain that can be tough to reach. Any recommendations on how to add a remote without replacing the fixture?
Thanks

Comment: Is it hardwired, or is it cord-and-plug connected?  Would you have the electrical chops to *make* it cord-and-plug-connected?  Would extending the chain make life easier (that is short work for a friendly neighborhood hardware store, note that Home Depot is not a friendly neighborhood hardware store).

Comment: i use an inline motion detector attachment, works great, easy to install.

Comment: It's hardwired and the walls are cinder block so there's no way to to hard wire a switch. I figure some sort of remote would be the easiest.

Comment: Extra long sting lead through a series of eye hooks (being sure the first one makes it easy on the fixture when you yank on it). Screw a hook to the inside door trim (I won't tell anybody ;)

Answer (score 1):

If it's hardwired you can add a switch on the feeding line, leave the pull-chain always on and use the remote switch instead. If you want to 'go smart' buy a [SonOff RF](http://sonoff.itead.cc/en/products/sonoff/sonoff-rf) device (the one compatible with 433MHz garage-door remote) with a remote, so you turn on the light it via remote or via app.

Comment: I ended up going with the acegoo Wireless Lights Switch Kit. Much cheaper than the SonOFF RF and a better remote for a light switch.